# Get count of elements in a specific column of a MySQL table for each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that has an array column whereas each element is delimited by a ",".  I am try to get a total count of all rows (145)

When I run the following code I am getting 145 for $index which is correct but $totalClasses is 0.  So obviously I am missing something.

I would appreciate it if someone would point out the error in my ways!

Thanks,

Vic

```
echo "<br><b>Number Classes Entered:</b>";
$SQL="SELECT ExhibitorClasses FROM tblShowEntries WHERE ShowID = $ShowID AND ExhibitorClasses IS NOT NULL AND ExhibitorClasses !=' '";


$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$myClasses = array(); // make a new array

$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) // loop to get the count
{
     $myClasses[$index] = $row;
     $userclasses = count($myClasses[$index]);
     $totalclasses = $totalclasses + $userClasses;
     $index++;
}

//  $userClasses = explode(",", $myClasses);
//  $totalclasses = count($myClasses);
echo $index . " " . $totalclasses
```

Comment: a picture or ascii representation of your table would be quite helpful, because u sound like using a 1NF form, which is a bad example of making tables

Comment: variables are case sensitive! `$userclasses` is not `$userClasses`

Comment: Blackbee - Actually I use SQLyog to create the table - not sure what a 1NF form is

Comment: Deadoosshka - oops mised that when I corrected it I get the same count as the index.  I tried this  :                             $userClasses = count(explode(",",$myClasses[$index]));  but it returns 0

Comment: A few things I noticed:  1) most of the code is camel case, I suggest totalclasses also be camel case.  2) totalclasses is not initialized, I suggest, before the loop, to set it to 0.  3) is userClasses actually numeric.  4) As I read the code, the rows are being copied, 1 by 1 into successive entries in the myClasses array.  So, count(myClasses[index]), I would expect would return, at most, 1.

Comment: if there is only one class per row, then only use count(myClasses) at the end to get a count of the rows.  otherwise, If each row can contain multiple classes, then the code needs to extract that class list, perhaps into an array, then count the array entries for each row.

Comment: @blackbee Pictures? Yuk, no thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

IN

```
$SQL="SELECT ExhibitorClasses FROM tblShowEntries WHERE ShowID = $ShowID AND ExhibitorClasses IS NOT NULL AND ExhibitorClasses !=' '";
```

you not concatenate var $ShowID correct is:

```
$SQL="SELECT ExhibitorClasses FROM tblShowEntries WHERE ShowID = ".$ShowID." AND ExhibitorClasses IS NOT NULL AND ExhibitorClasses !=' '";
```

Comment: Luciano - Don't think it really has to be concatenated as $ShowID will get resolved without concatenation.  However, I did that but same results

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who responded - Here is my final code. There may be a better way to do this but it works so guess thats ok.

```
$SQL="SELECT ExhibitorClasses FROM tblShowEntries WHERE ShowID = ".$ShowID." AND ExhibitorClasses IS NOT NULL AND ExhibitorClasses !=' '";

$result = mysql_query($SQL);
$myClasses = array(); // make a new array to hold my classes
$totalClasses=0;
$index = 0;

$query = mysql_query($SQL);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) // loop
{
    $myClasses[$index] = $row[0];
    $classes = explode(",", $myClasses[$index]);
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($classes as $item) {
       $count++;
    }
    $totalClasses = $totalClasses + $count;
    $index++;
}
echo "<br><b>Number Classes Entered:</b> ".$totalClasses;
```